# My HC-05 Bluetooth module is not receiving correct data

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to built a LED blinker using HC-05, but I encountered an error.

Here is the Arduino code:

```cpp
int data = 0;            //Variable for storing received data
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);   //Sets the baud for serial data transmission                               
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  //Sets digital pin 13 as output pin
}
void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available())      // Send data only when you receive data:
   {
      data = Serial.read();        //Read the incoming data & store into data
      Serial.print(data);          //Print Value inside data in Serial monitor
      Serial.print("\n");        
      if(data == 1)              // Checks whether value of data is equal to 1
         digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   //If value is 1 then LED turns ON
      else if(data == 0)         //  Checks whether value of data is equal to 0
         digitalWrite(13, LOW);    //If value is 0 then LED turns OFF
   }
}
```

No matter which button I press on or off, the value of int data will remain same (255).

I also used many apps so I think it is not an app problem.

Comment: How's the connection with HC-05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this problem.

Just change the baud rate and observe the output. My module is working perfectly on 38400.

I hope this will help you out.